# Jasmine - Test a service that returns a localStorage item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-service

I have an authentication service that stores the current user object in the localStorage when a user logs in successfully. This service is used by many other services. A service, say ABCService calls a method in the authentication service to get the token required for communication. The spec for ABCService fails in grunt test, and says this:

```
    TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'ABCConfig.getUser().token')
```

Obviously the token is set only when the user is logged in. How to get rid of this? Or in other words, how to test this right?

Comment: You could test 2 cases -- one when the user is logged in, and emulate a login before testing, and one case when the user is logged out, removing any local storage information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Jasmine testing with Angular and I'm struggling to get around it! So emulating the login is alien to me!

Comment: Basically what you could do is set up a fake `localStorage` entry using a `beforeEach` function.

Comment: How to do that? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Something along the lines of this http://jsfiddle.net/t4avfa28/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please let me check it out.

Comment: Close enough! How would I emulate the actual login procedure which uses an AJAX call?

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- which version of jasmine are you using?

Answer (score -1):

To solve your issue you can emulate a logged in state with a fake local storage entry along the lines of this:

```
describe("when user is logged in", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        // ensure a user is logged in
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'testUser');
    });

    it("should work", function () {
        // run function, it should work
    });
});
```

It also opens up a possibility to test how the service behaves if there is no user data in `localStorage`:

```
describe("when user is logged out", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
    });

    it("should fail", function () {
        // something along the lines of
        // expect(ABCConfig.getUser().token).toBeNull();
    });
});
```

In regards to the question about async calls, Jasmine in 2.0.0+ provides a callback method as an argument of `it`, `beforeEach` and `afterEach` anonymous functions. It looks like this:

```
describe("when user is logged in", function () {
    beforeEach(function (done) {
        // ensure a user is logged in
        logInFunction(done); // pass done as a callback
    });

    it("should work", function () {
        // run function, it should work
    });
});
```

With this, the tests will proceed only once the `done` callback has been called in `beforeEach` block.

More info [here.](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)